# Manually build a serializable collection in Laravel

Tags: json, rest, serialization, laravel, laravel-4

I'm programming a **RESTful service** with **Laravel**. Now I have some trouble with serializing a manually created list of objects.

I have a `User` object that should have an attribute `solarpanels`. This attribute I realised with an accessor like this:

```
function getSolarplantsAttribute() {
    $solarplants = array();
    $mastergrants = MasterGrant::where('userid', '=', $this->id)->get();
    foreach ($mastergrants as $mastergrant) {
        $masternode = Masternode::find($mastergrant->masternodeid);
        if ($masternode == null) {
            continue;
        }
        $solarplant = SolarPlant::find($masternode->fieldID);
        $solarplants[] = $solarplant;
    }
    return $solarplants;
}
```

Unfortunately, I have to do it in this complicated fashion, as that's how the database scheme is designed and I can't change it.

Now I have a **Resource Controller**, that I wanted to realise in this way:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $solarplants = $user->solarplants;
    return $solarplants;
}
```

Unfortunately, this way the objects get serialized as:

```
[{"timestamps":false,"incrementing":true,"exists":true}]
```

This is wrong, it's only seralizing the object variables, but not how it should be done and how I designed the **Eloquent Object**. So what I tried, is to do this:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $solarplants = $user->solarplants;
    $convertedPlants = array();
    foreach ($solarplants as $solarplant) {
        $convertedPlants[] = $solarplant->toJson();
    }
    return $convertedPlants;
}
```

This kind of worked, but now Laravel is escaping my JSON string, which does change the JSON's meaning and thus is *not processable anymore* in the frontend. I also tried to cast it like this: `$solarplant->toArray()`, but then the **accessors** of the `SolarPlant` object get ignored.

Then I had another idea (as when I do `return SolarPlant::all();` works and gets serialized perfectly fine). I wanted to create a **Collection** manually. But this again results in a way that the accessors don't get properly serialized.

So basically, I have no proper solution for my problem yet. Does any of you have an advice?

**EDIT for simplification:**

I try to explain the core of the problem a bit more simple and abstract. My `SolarPlant` object is an eloquent object, that has accessors. This accessors themselves return single eloquent objects or lists of eloquent objects. Now when I do this, everything works fine:

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    return SolarPlant::find(1);
});
```

But this way, the serialization doesn't work anymore, it's serializing the raw php objects instead of doing it in the eloquent way:

```
Route::get('test', function () {
  $solarplants = array();
  $solarplants[] = SolarPlant::find(1);
  $solarplants[] = SolarPlant::find(1);
  return $solarplants;
});
```

But what I also just figured out, is that the SolarPlant::all() doesn't work properly as I expected. The accessors don't get processed well too.

Comment: do you mean accessor not mutators? You don't set here anything so I think you wanted to use accessor, right?

Comment: you're right, I got confused over the naming, edited it.

Comment: And what is `SolarPlants::all` ? Do you have 2 models `SolarPlant` and `SolarPlants`?

Comment: excuse me, that was a mistake, it should be SolarPlant::all(). But in my code it was correct ;)

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to help you any more with this. I don't see any problem here. Everything should work

Answer (score 0):

You can override SolarPlant toArray/toJson method to include what you want:

```
class SolarPlant {
    ...
    public function toArray() {
        $array = parent::toArray();
        $array['mutator_x'] = $this->mutator_x;
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, that's not working. I have my accessors in the $appends array. And as I said, returning SolarPlant:all() serializes right and also returning SolarPlant:find(1) does.

Answer (score 0):

If you simple want `JSON` format you can leave your `getSolarplantsAttribute` unchanged and modify your `index` function to:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    return json_encode($user->solarplants);
}
```

And if you have any accessor for `SolarPlant` they will be executed.

I've tested it and it seems to work fine, accessor is launched. I added the following accessor:

```
public function getEmailAttribute() {
    return mb_strtoupper($this->attributes['email']);
}
```

and when I get users in the same way, I get email in uppercase (and in database is in lowercase).

I've tested it changing your `getSolarplantsAttribute` function into:

```
function getSolarplantsAttribute()
{
    $users[] = User::find($this->id);
    $users[] = User::find($this->id);
    return $users;
}
```

and I got expected result

Comment: When I tried it, it returned me [{"timestamps":false,"incrementing":true,"exists":true}]. So it didn't serialize in Eloquent-Style, but only the rare PHP-Object. Why? (EDIT: I have only 1 solarplant in my dummy databse, that's why it's only one json object in the list)

Comment: @Chris try to change your `getSolarplantsAttribute` into something really basic. I put there `$users[] = User::find(1); $users[] = User::find(1); return $users;` just to test it

Comment: Mh, I couldn't get it to work. I update my original post to make it a bit more simple and make my problem easier to grasp.